# How revert changes after doing undo stage

Tags: git, visual-studio

After I made a change to the file in the project under Git and before I added or committed it, I did an undo changes and now I want to return the changes I made.
What is the required command?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by an "undo" stage,   Did you do `git checkout <filename>` ?  If so, I,m afraid it's not recoverable,  iif you did `git stash` you can recover them with `git stash pop` or `git stash apply`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn thanks. I work with the git changes tool of Visual Studio and there is an "undo changes" button

Comment: Aha, so this is a question about using VS, not about using Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`undo changes` will discard any changes you made to the file since the last commit.

You cannot undo undone changes. That's why you had to confirm a dialog that asked if you were sure you wanted to do this.

If you want to undo changes that you can add again later stash them.